# calculating variance in a queueing model which looping flow

Tags: variance, queueing

For the verification of a Discrete Event Model of a queueing model that I programmed, I would like to calculate the steady state values of the queueing times at different stations and their variance

The system consists of two cells (C1, C2) with different numbers of servers and a looping stream. Arriving clients are put in the queue of server 1. After serving at 1 the client moves to cell 2. After being served at 2 the client returns to the same queue it arrived in at cell 1 and awaits its turn. After the second serving at cell 1, it departs the system. The system has a arrival rate and a departure rate that are to be equal for a steady state: $ r_{a} = r_{d} $ Additionally server 1 has a handling rate that is twice the handling rate of cell 2 and the total system throughput: $ 2r_{a} = 2r_{d} = 2r_{a,S2} = r_{a,S1} $ Defined are:

- The arrival rate: $ r_{a} $ and its variance $ \sigma_{a}^2 $
- The server times: $ r_{a,S1} $, $r_{a,S2} $ and variance $ \sigma_{a,S1}^2 $, $ \sigma_{a,S2}^2 $

This concludes the arrival rate at cell 1 is:

$ r_{a,C1} = r_{a} + r_{d,C2} $ with $ \sigma_{a,C1}^2 = \sigma_{a}^2 + \sigma_{d,C2}^2 $

and the arrival rate at cell 2 is:

$ r_{a,C2} = \frac{1}{2}r_{d,C1} = r_{a} $ with $ \sigma_{d,C1}^2 = \frac{1}{4} \sigma_{a,C1}^2 $

For the departure coefficient of variability is known for a cell utility:

$ c_d^2 = 1 +(1-u^2)(c_a^2-1) + \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{m}}(c_e^2-1) $

with the coefficient of variability being:$ c_n = \frac{\sigma_n^2}{t_e^2} $
and the cell utility: $ u = \frac{r_{a}t_{e}}{m}$
here $ m $ is the number of servers in the cell.

How is the variability or coefficient of variance, $ \sigma_{a,S1}^2 $, $ c_{a,S1}$ respectively defined explicitly?

[image: Schematical overview of servers and flows]